# SQL query to test if string value contains carriage return

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison, sql-like

Trying to figure out the right way to test if a VARCHAR column value ends with a carriage return. Tried this but it does not work, database is `Oracle 11g`...

```
select name from myTable where name LIKE '%\r' OR name like '%\n'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find a value that contains non-printable characters such as carriage return or vertical tab or end of line you can use [regexp_like](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) function. In your case to display rows where a string value of a particular column contains carriage return at the end the similar query can be used.

```
select *
  from your_table_name
 where regexp_like(trim(string_column), '[[:space:]]$')
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5f4a/1)

---

**Answer to the comments**

`Trim` function, by default, deletes leading and trailing spaces and it will not delete **carriage return** or **end of line** characters. Lets carry out a simple test:

```
SQL> create table Test_Table(
  2    id number,
  3    col1 varchar2(101)
  4  );

Table created

SQL> insert into Test_Table (id, col1)
  2    values(1, 'Simple string');

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> insert into Test_Table (id, col1)
  2    values(1, 'Simple string with carriage return at the end' || chr(13));

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> insert into Test_Table (id, col1)
  2    values(1, '   Simple string with carriage return at the end leading and trailing spaces' || chr(13)||'   ');

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> insert into Test_Table (id, col1)
  2    values(1, '  Simple string leading and trailing spaces  ');

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select *
  2    from test_table;

        ID COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Simple string
         1 Simple string with carriage return at the end
         1    Simple string with carriage return at the end leading and trailing spaces
         1   Simple string leading and trailing spaces

SQL> 
SQL> select *
  2    from test_table
  3   where regexp_like(trim(col1), '[[:space:]]$')
  4  ;

        ID COL1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Simple string with carriage return at the end
         1    Simple string with carriage return at the end leading and trailing spaces

SQL>
```

Comment: What part of `[[:space:]]$` is actually checking for the carriage return? Is it `$` ?

Comment: `[[:space:]]` - looking for carriage return(and other non-printable characters mentioned in the answer). `$` - search for matches at the end of the string.

Comment: I tried this, but it's picking up columns with spaces at the end, definitely skipping over those with carriage returns... BTW, +1 for SQLFiddle!

Comment: trim the column value as `trim(col_name)`

Comment: Actually, this is working, we found other instances of data where it's occurring, not where we expected, though. Thx

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
SELECT name from myTable where name like '%'||chr(10) or name like '%'||chr(13)
```

Comment: The correct numbers to use will depend on the database character set for [var]char[2] types and database national character set for n[var]char[2] types. (Commented on the off chance anybody using EBCDIC runs across this answer.)